# angular.js:11607 TypeError: fn is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I am facing a problem with this link below which I want to  use in my code,Its working fine but I am getting one error whenever I click on add fields button.

http://www.shanidkv.com/blog/angularjs-adding-form-fields-dynamically

The Error is as follows,

```
angular.js:11607 TypeError: fn is not a function
    at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12346)
    at callback (angular.js:21435)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:14401)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14500)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:21440)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.v.handle (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
```

Comment: The tutorial works well. The problem comes from your code, not this one.

Comment: Like Mistalis mentioned, it seems to be an error in your code. If you need help with your it, please post it with your question.